# Is there a standard way to fail pytest if test coverage falls under x%

Tags: python, pytest, code-coverage

Right now the way I'm running things is I have a set of test cases written with pytest that I run, if they fail then I fix and rework on. If they pass I use pytest-cov to get coverage and manually decide whether coverage is good enough. I was wondering if it was possible for pytest to fail if threshold for coverage is under x amount.

```
pytest --cov=myproject tests --cov-report=html
coverage report --fail-under=80
....
myproject/services/subnet.py                                                                        36     33     8%
myproject/severity.py                                                                                5      0   100%
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                                                                             8843   8739     1%
....
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should use pytest for running tests, and failing if the tests fail.  Then use coverage to assess the coverage amount, and fail if it is under:

```
pytest --cov=mypackage --cov-report= tests-or-whatever
coverage report --fail-under=80
```

Comment: Hmm, `coverage report --fail-under=80` doesn't seem to do anything but spit out the sameoutput pytest had. This is what I'm running (edited)

Comment: "coverage report" will exit with a failure status if the total is too low. But now that you mention it, it seem obvious that it should also display a message in the output. I've written an issue: https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/issues/904

Comment: So this one just tells me that the recipe failed. Is it possible to get a more friendly message?

Comment: @qasimzee for me, the console shows this message, so it's clear what the threashold and the actual coverage are: `FAIL Required test coverage of 50% not reached. Total coverage: 38.10%`

Comment: see `--cov-fail-under=90`

Answer (score 20):

If you are using [`pytest-cov`](https://pytest-cov.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), you can use [`--cov-fail-under=MIN`](https://pytest-cov.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html?highlight=cov-fail-under#reference):

```
pytest --cov-fail-under=80 [...]
```